# Laravel 5.1 Server - Class not found

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel 5.1 project. On my scotchbox (vagrant) everything works perfectly, but when I deploy it on the server I get this error

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class
>   'League\ColorExtractor\Laravel\ColorExtractorServiceProvider' not
>   found

I'm guessing it's a permission issue, but I tried to solve it and nothing seems to work.

The project folder: drwxr-x--- owned by apache.

Edit

After commenting the Colorextractor alias and provider and trying again, the website loads but when I add something with the COlorextractor I get;

> FatalErrorException in
>   /home/boost/vendor/league/colorextractor/src/League/ColorExtractor/Client.php
>   line 14: Call to undefined function
>   League\ColorExtractor\imagecreatefrompng()

Comment: Honestly undefined errors like this when switching servers is usually caused by not generating the autoloader. Have you run ```composer update``` on the new server?

Comment: @MikelBitson Don't `update`, only `install`!

Comment: @Sven Yes- I apologize, depending on your requirements, only install as to not load in new updates to packages. Typically in development it's a solid practice to use update if you want everything to be updated and working when it's ready for production- this way you encounter any issues and fix them before pushing them into production.

Comment: I ran both update and install @MikelBitson

Comment: I'm trying to play with the permissions on the storage folder, but now I get a server error 500

Comment: Did the permission change alone present you with a 500 error? What did you change the permissions of the storage folder to to get the 500? Are you certain composer completed successfully? Are you seeing a composer.lock file on the new server? It still seems like an issue with the autoloading process, not permissions- though it very well could be either.

Comment: Yes I see the composer.lock. COmposer did install perfectly. When I comment the lines in the config/app.php file I get a new error (see updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using;

> ```
> yum install php56w-gd
> systemctl httpd restart
> ```